# What is the standard OCaml data structure with fastest iteration?

Tags: performance, data-structures, ocaml

I'm looking for a container that provides *fastest unordered iterations* through the encapsulated elements.  In other words, "add once, iterate many times".

Is there one among OCaml's standard modules that is fast enough (such that further optimization of it would be useless)?  Or some kind of third-party GPL-ready ones?

AFAIK there's just one OCaml compiler, so the concept of being fast is more or less clear...

...But after I saw a couple of answers, it appears, it's not.  Of course, there's a plenty of data structures that allow O(n) iteration through container of size n.  But the task I'm solving is one of those, where difference between O(n) and O(2n) matters ;-).

I also see that *Arrays and Lists provide unnecessary information about the order of elements added*, which I don't need.  Maybe in "functional world" there exists data structures such that can trade this information for a bit of iteration speed.

In C I would outright pick a plain array.  The question is, what should I pick in OCaml?

Comment: 1) To be pedantic, there is no difference between O(n) and O(2n). You're talking about constant factors. 2) Choosing an arbitrary order for the elements and fixing it, as in an array or list, is exactly how you optimize for iteration. How do you expect to improve on "increment an index/follow a pointer, fetch from memory" for iteration speed?

Comment: 1) Yes, I am talking about constant factors, since I'm optimizing the bottleneck; 2) I don't know how to improve that, but is *it* the way Array and List modules work?  Array is not *said* (while it *may* be *known*) to occupy consecutive memory. List needs pointer dereference (slow?). I'm still in doubt.

Comment: @Pavel: What Chris is saying is that you're abusing Big O notation. He's not saying you shouldn't care about constant factors, only that you should be more clear in your mathematical notation when referring to them.

Comment: @bcat, why so serious? ;-)  I mean, I assume that everyone who reads questions in [ocaml] tag, does know what it means and can detect  jokes, even if they're not so good :-\

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are unlikely to do better than built-in arrays and lists, since they are hand-coded in C, unless you bind to your own native implementation of an iterator. An array will behave almost exactly like an array in C (a contiguously allocated block of memory containing a sequence of element values), possibly with some extra pointer indirections due to boxing. List are implemented exactly how you would expect: as cells with a value and a "next" pointer. Arrays will give you the best locality for unboxed types (especially `float`s, which have a super-special unboxed implementation).

For information about the implementation of arrays and lists, see [Section 18.3 of the OCaml manual](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual032.html#toc130) and the files `byterun/mlvalues.h`, `byterun/array.c`, and `byterun/alloc.c` in the OCaml source code.

**From the questioner**: indeed, `Array` appeared to be the fastest solution.  However it only outperformed `List` by 7%.  Maybe it was because the type of an array element was not plain enough: it was an algebraic type.  `Hashtbl` performed 4 times worse, as expected.

So, I will pick `Array` and I'm accepting this one. good.

Comment: This is quite old but the whole question got moved to the top for some reason. Let me note that lists are not hand-coded in C, they are defined as a usual algebraic datatype. Modulo some syntactic sugar for convenience, it's just `type 'a list = Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a list`. The good performance is explained by good representation choices for OCaml datatypes, not specialization. Arrays are built-in and do have better locality, though.

Answer (score 8):

**To know for sure, you're going to have to measure**.  Based on the machine instructions the compiler is likely to generate, I would try an array, then a list.

- Access to an array element requires a bounds check, address arithmetic, and a load
- Access to the head of a list requires a load, a test for empty list, and a load at a known compile-time offset.

The details of which is faster probably depend on your application and what else is happening on your machine.  They also depend on the type of elements; for example, if they are floating-point numbers, `ocamlopt` may be clever enough to make an unboxed array, which will save you a level of indirection.

Other common data structures like hash tables or balanced trees generally require that you allocate some context somewhere to keep track of where you are.  With an array, keeping track requires only an integer index; with a list, keeping track requires a single pointer.  I think this is going to be hard to beat in another data structure.

Finally please note that there may be only one OCaml compiler, but it has *two* back ends: bytecode and native code.  Naturally if you care about this level of performance, you are using the native-code `ocamlopt` version.  Right?

Please take measurements and edit the results into your question.

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget about `Bigarray`s, they are most close to C arrays (just a flat piece of memory), but cannot contain arbitrary OCaml values. Also consider switching bounds checking off (unsafe_set/get). And of course you should profile first.

Answer (score 3):

The array - a linear piece of memory with the items visited in sequential order - best utilises the CPU's L1 data cache.

Comment: It was true in C... is it still the fastest in OCaml?

Comment: If it's an unboxed datatype (e.g., integers), the array values will be stored in a contiguous block of memory. If it's a "boxed" datatype (most are), then it will be an array of pointers, so you probably won't gain much over a list.

Answer (score 1):

All common data structures are iterable in O(n) time, so the differences between data structures will only be constant (and very probably not significant).

At least lists and arrays allow iteration without significant overhead. I can't think of a situation where that would not be fast enough.